# React Router v6 redirects URL with query params to url without queryparams

Tags: reactjs, react-router, query-string

I'm using React router v6 and facing an issue where if I access any route using query params, I'm automatically redirected to whichever URL I'm on but without query params.

For example:

mywebsite.com/somePage?id=1234 --> mywebsite.com/somePage

Here's my routing component:

```
 <BrowserRouter>
  <NavigationLayout auth={auth} setAuth={setAuth} setIsClient={setIsClient} isClient={isClient}>
    <Routes>
      <>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/register"
          element={
            auth.email ? (
              <Navigate to="/"></Navigate>
            ) : (
              <Register auth={auth} setAuth={setAuth} />
            )
          }
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/login"
          element={
            auth.email ? (
              <Navigate to="/"></Navigate>
            ) : (
              <Login setIsClient={setIsClient} auth={auth} setAuth={setAuth} />
            )
          }
        />
         
         <Route
          
          path="/clients"
          element={
            auth.email ? (
              <ClientForm auth={auth} setAuth={setAuth} />
            ) : (
              <ClientsLogin auth={auth} setAuth={setAuth} setIsClient={setIsClient}/>
            )
          }
        />
      </>

      <Route exact path="/form/one" element={<FormPageOne />} />
      <Route exact path="/form/two" element={<FormPageTwo />} />
      <Route exact path="/form/three" element={<FormPageThree />} />
      <Route exact path="/form/four" element={<FormPageFour />} />
      <Route exact path="/form/five" element={<FormPageFive />} />
      <Route exact path="/form/six" element={<FormPageSix />} />
      <Route exact path="/form/seven" element={<FormPageSeven />} />
      <Route exact path="/profile" element={<Profile auth={auth} setAuth={setAuth}/>} />
      <Route exact path="/tyc" element={<Terms/>} />

      <Route
        path="/"
        element={
          auth.email ? (
            <FormPageOne />
          ) : (
            <Login setIsClient={setIsClient} auth={auth} setAuth={setAuth} />
          )
        }
      />
     
    </Routes>
  </NavigationLayout>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: `react-router-dom` uses the path part of the URL for matching and rendering routes and routed content. The queryString isn't used by RRD. What are you expecting to be matched and rendered? Are you saying that the queryString is getting stripped out of the URL? If so can you provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the code that does this?